# Maintain Execution order Celery

Tags: python, celery

I have a situation where I need to process some data in the background using Celery. The main task launches two subtasks; I would like to enforce the order of execution of the subtasks. The reason behind this enforcement is the second subtask depend on the completion of the first subtask. Otherwise, the second subtask would end in maximum recursion error.

```
a = group([perform_driver_calibration.s(task, portfolio_id, scenario_id) for task in tasks])
b = group([model_field_compile.s(task, model_field, scenario_id)
           for task, model_field in zip(tasks, ModelFields.objects(PortfolioModelId=portfolio_model_id))])
```

I want to perform task `a`; upon completion task `b` should start.

This is what I did to make the execution in order but still it's out of order sometimes.

```
# Order of execution is VERY important
# 1. Driver Calibration
# 2. Field Calculation
chain(a(), b())
```

How to prioritize subtasks in celery?

Comment: What version of celery are you using?

Comment: Latest stable version - 3.1.18

Comment: I believe it is because of the `()` after the a and b.   because they are already groups I believe you should be calling it like such `chain(a,b).delay()`